# rails selecting the current menu title by url

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to highlight the relevant menu item by the current url.

here is the html

```
       <ul class="nav">
          <li>
            <a href="/ratings">Rate</a>
          </li>
          <li class="">
            <a href="/ratings/list">All Pics</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="/ratings/new">Upload Your Own</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

and the simple jquery:

```
$(function () {
    var active = 'active',
        $lastMatch,
        s = window.location.pathname;

    $('.nav a').each(function (index, item) {
        if (s.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) !== -1) {
            $lastMatch = $(this).closest('li');
        }
    });

    if ($lastMatch.length){
        $lastMatch.addClass(active);
    }
});
```

works. 
**But** if I navigate to url `0.0.0.0:3000/ratings/list/1` which is different the `` `0.0.0.0:3000/ratings/list `` then a weird bug happens and it does stay 'active'.

I tried debugging with fire bug and I see that the li gets the `active` class but it gets canceled out by something else and i have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your following line:

```
if (s.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) !== -1) {
```

for this one:

```
if (s.indexOf($(this).attr("href"), s.length - $(this).attr("href").length) !== -1) {
```

So to compare if both strings match **at the end** of the string, instead of in any part like you were doing. This way you can avoid the corner case you are having.

Comment: hi nelson, I tried it and it didnt work(didnt go inside the loop at all). As I stated, the relevant li gets the `active` class at the end of the js script, but Something cancels it afterward in the case of `ratings/list/x`, maybe it's a rails issue..